# ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed

Tags: c#, sql

My Code :

```
public bool Insertcustomer()
{
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insertcustomermaster", dal.con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@customercode", SqlDbType.Int).Value = customercode;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@customername", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = customername;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@address1", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = address1;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@address2", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = address1;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@phoneno", SqlDbType.Int).Value = phoneno;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@mobileno", SqlDbType.Int).Value = mobileno;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@mailid", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = mailid;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@website", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = website;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@occupation", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = occupation;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@status", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = status;


        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        return Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery());  //Error
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

**App Config :**

im new in c# .net..im not able to find this error..anybody help..

Comment: When you say your new to program, then you must first read MSDN/related articles about this. I dont see the use of opening a thread here with out reading about it.

Comment: You need to dispose `SqlCommand`, and `SqlConnection` as soon as you've finished using them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is Connecting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705637/executereader-requires-an-open-and-available-connection-the-connections-curren)

Answer (score 2):

You should open the connection and close it .

```
string connectionString = "";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
con.Open();

//do your coding 
con.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message says what's wrong. The connection is not open, but closed.

Ensure the connection is opened. Use the `Open()`-Method to open a connection.

BTW, get rid of the try/catch-block. What's the point in catching an exception and throw it again?

Answer (score 1):

From your code you would need to open the connection specified in the SqlCommand declaration (`dal.con`)

You should open it with

```
dal.con.Open()
```

before you ExecuteNonQuery but remember to close it after (`dal.con.Close()`).

I would suggest changing

```
return Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery());
```

to

```
dal.con.Open();
bool result = Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery());
dal.con.Close();
return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

`dal.con` hasn't been set or opened or whatever. As per the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post more information regarding the connection string?

Try this in the Webconfig:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="connName" connectionString="//ConnectionString here"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

In the Class:

```
public static SqlConnection GetConnection()
{
    string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connName"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
    return con;
}
```

And instead of this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insertcustomermaster", dal.con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@customercode", SqlDbType.Int).Value = customercode;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@customername", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = customername;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@address1", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = address1;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@address2", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = address1;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@phoneno", SqlDbType.Int).Value = phoneno;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@mobileno", SqlDbType.Int).Value = mobileno;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@mailid", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = mailid;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@website", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = website;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@occupation", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = occupation;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@status", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = status;


        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        return Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery());  //Error
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
```

Do this:

```
//Method + Insert string (Guessing you want to create a register page)
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, GetConnection());
    //You don't have to point out the data type if it's just going to be filled in like that.
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customercode", customercode);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customername", customername);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address1", address1);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address2", address2);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phoneno", phoneno);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobileno", mobileno);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mailid", mailid);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@website", website);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@occupation", occupation);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", status);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
        {
            // You can catch it with an error, or Just leave it empty
            string msg = "Error";
            msg += ex.Message;
            throw new Exception(msg);
        }
        //Close the connection (Not Necessary)
        GetConnection().Close();
    }
```