# VB.net Changing stored procedure within an sql connection

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures, shortcut, sqlconnection

I am making a page that will run multiple stored procedures on load to pre-populate textboxes on a page.

Rather than opening and closing a connection every time I want to use a different stored procedure I wondered if it would be possible to change it multiple times within one connection.

eg this:

```
Using myConnection1 = New SqlConnection("connectionString")
 myConnection1.Open()
 Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand("storedProdure1", myConnection)
 myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

 'additional code here

 End Using

Using myConnection2 = New SqlConnection("connectionString")

 myConnection2.Open()
 Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand("storeProcedure2", myConnection2)
 myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

 'additional code here

End Using
```

could be replaced with something like this:

```
Using myConnection1 = New SqlConnection("connectionString")
 myConnection1.Open()
 Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand("storedProdure1", myConnection)
 myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

 'additional code here

myCommand.alterSqlCommand("storedProcdure2", myConnection)

 'additional code here

 End Using
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using normal SQL Commands you can just write:

```
myCommand.CommandText = "..."
```

and change the command while having an open connection. 
The same should work for Stored Procedures. Just use `CommandText` to change the StoredProcedure.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

After browsing for an answer to something somewhat related (reusing an sqldatareader) I found the following question which was answered both my queries.

[Reuse of SqlConnection and SqlDataReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146979/reuse-of-sqlconnection-and-sqldatareader)