# Static methods vs instance methods in BLL

Tags: c#

Was asked today why I used code like this for my bll classes in an asp.net app:

```
public class StudentBll
{
    public static DataTable GetStudents()
    {
        return DBHelper.ExecuteSp("GetStudents");
    }
    public static DataTable GetStudentById(int studentId) 
    {
        return DBHelper.ExecuteSp("GetStudentById", studentId);
    }
}
```

instead of

```
public class StudentBll
{
    public DataTable GetStudents()
    {
        return DBHelper.ExecuteSp("GetStudents");
    }
    public DataTable GetStudentById(int studentId) 
    {
        return DBHelper.ExecuteSp("GetStudentById", studentId);
    }
}
```

Only thing I could think of was that

A) **Performance** A slight increase (not sure of the specifics)

B) **Readability**
 `StudentBll.GetStudents();` rather than

```
StudentBll studentBll = new StudentBll();
studentBll.GetStudents();
```

I wasn't too confident in those answers, however.  Anyone care to enlighten me?

Comment: Does `StudentBll` also has any static members?

Comment: @TimSchmelter - It only contains public static methods.

Comment: what does BLL stand for?

Comment: @payo: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_logic_layer

Comment: @TimSchmelter thanks, never used the tla for that (we just call it the business _layer_) meh, potato pahtahto

Comment: @白ジェームス: and you don't use any static ado.net objects(f.e. connections) in them?

Comment: @TimSchmelter - correct.  connections/datareaders/etc are all contained within the DAL.

Comment: @白ジェームス: Are they created in the methods or are they reused from somewhere?

Comment: @TimSchmelter - The DBHelper class is reused every place I need to call a stored procedure (see modified code above).  It only contains methods that derive stored procedure parameters and logic to execute said stored procedure.

Comment: @白ジェームス: As feared, does the `DBHelper` class reuse ado.net objects(especially a connection) or does it always create  new instances with  `using-statement` inside of these methods? This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705637/executereader-requires-an-open-and-available-connection-the-connections-curren/9707060#9707060

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Oh, I see where you are going with this.  Um, the call to ExecuteSp is always doing a try { connection.Open(); table.Load(someReader); } finally { connection.Close(); }

Comment: @白ジェームス: You haven't still answered whether the connection is also static or not. To cut a long story short: if it's created in `ExecuteSp` everything is ok, apart from what Austin has said :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Ya, the connection is not static, just the method that creates it (ExecuteSp).  Thanks Tim, you had me worried!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With respect to performance, if you can't show what the increase is, then it does not support your claim.  One could also argue that the performance gain by a static method call vs an instance method call is negligible to that of the round-trip travel & database time.

You've also locked down your implementation (or at least forced the consumers to do something harder to modify).  If you lost the static methods and code to an interface, testers and developers of different tiers could build mocks so they wouldn't be forced to use whatever you provide them.

Comment: Austin - true, this was not designed for testing, as all tests in this case are integration tests with the sprocs.  I see your points, however.

Answer (score 2):

Testability is the first thing that comes to my mind, when I see public static methods. Also forget about oop - no inheritance here (both classes and interfaces) thus you don't have class instances. No inheritance means no abstraction. No abstraction means tight coupling.