# InvalidOperationException The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, t-sql

Why does this code throw an Invalid Operation Exception?

```
private SqlCommand cmd; // initialized in the class constructor

public void End(string spSendEventNotificationEmail) {
  try {
    cmd.CommandText = spSendEventNotificationEmail;
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@packetID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = _packetID;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@statusID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = _statusID;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@website", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = Tools.NextStep;
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  } finally {
    cmd.Connection.Close();
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.Dispose();
  }
  endCall = true;
}
```

[image: InvalidOperationException]

Comment: Maybe you have opened your connection before?

Comment: I think that the root of the problem is in the instance of SqlCommand initialized at the class constructor. Having this var around in all of your code could be easily misused and leading to nasty bugs in other parts of your code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9707060/4068

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to open a connection which is already open, this results in exception.

**Solution 1 (recommended):**

Inspect your code, check all the parts where `cmd.Connection` connection is opened and ensure that it's always closed properly.

**Solution 2 (quick'n'dirty fix):**

before line

```
cmd.Connection.Open();
```

add the following check/cleanup code:

```
if (cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
    cmd.Connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Bleh! Freakin' noobie mistakes.

Comment: Well, this could do the job, however the OP code hightlights the ExecuteNonQuery line, not the Connection.Open

Answer (score 6):

There's very little need for keeping the Sql* objects at the class level, especially based on what you're showing.  You'll also lose the benefits of connection pooling by attempting to do it yourself.

With this method, you remove the possibility of your error because you're not sharing any objects

```
private readonly _connectionString = "...";

public void End(string spSendEventNotificationEmail) {
  using(var conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
  using(var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
  {
    cmd.CommandText = spSendEventNotificationEmail;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@packetID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = _packetID;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@statusID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = _statusID;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@website", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = Tools.NextStep;
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
  endCall = true;
}
```

Comment: The only reason I initially created it this way was so that several part numbers from a single request could share the same transaction. I've found a better way to do that, though, so I could (probably should) ditch this old method anyway. Thanks.