# Using statement in c# does not close the connection. Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, using

I am creating a crud gridview webpage and I am using the "using" statement in ASP.NET in my code because I learned that it automatically converts the code that is inside it so I won't have to use `connect.Close();`

But still, I am getting an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.

I tried to put `connection.Close();` but still, the same error occurs.

This is my code. Can anyone please help me solve the problem? Thank you so much

```
void PopulateGridView()
{
    using (connect)
    {
        connect.Open();
        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM RetailInfo", connect);
        table = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(table);
    }

    if(table.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        RetailInfoGridView.DataSource = table;
        RetailInfoGridView.DataBind();
    } 
    else
    {
        table.Rows.Add(table.NewRow());
        RetailInfoGridView.DataSource = table;
        RetailInfoGridView.DataBind();
        RetailInfoGridView.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
        RetailInfoGridView.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
        RetailInfoGridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = table.Columns.Count;
        RetailInfoGridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "No record Found";
    }
}
```

Comment: that connection variable is used again somewhere else in your application

Comment: Does this answer your question? [InvalidOperationException The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053731/invalidoperationexception-the-connection-was-not-closed-the-connections-curren)

Comment: On which line does the error occur? Is `connect` of type `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection`?

Comment: `using (connect)` should be `using (var connect = new SqlConnection(connectionString))` BTW, `adapter.Fill` will open the connection if it's closed, so you don't need the `connect.Open()` line.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I solved it. He is right. I used  the variable connection 3 times. THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I really appreciated it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple fix is before connect.Open(), you can do the following:

```
if (connect.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
    connect.Close();
}
```

Also, as Zohar Peled indicated that its good to use `using (var connect = new SqlConnection(connectionString))` instead of declaring objects at the class level.

This way there are no leaks and connection objects are disposed as soon as their work is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this part

```
 using (connect)
    {
       connect.Open();
        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM RetailInfo", connect);
        table = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(table);
     }
```

to

```
using (connect)
    {
        if (connect.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        connect.Close();
        connect.Open();
        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM RetailInfo", connect);
        table = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(table);
        connect.Close();
    }
```