# The name 'sqlDbType' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm going to edit textbox value.. but i saw there's a problem

```
  protected void btn_edit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DatabaseConnector con = new DatabaseConnector().CreateInstance();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tbl_BinCardManager SET ItemName = @ItemName WHERE ItemNo = @ItemNo");
        com.Parameters.Add("@ItemName",sqlDbType.VarChar);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

    }
```

ERROR 1:

> The name 'sqlDbType' does not exist in the current context

ERROR 2:

> 'ERPSystem.DatabaseConnector' does not contain a definition for 'Open'
>   and no extension method 'Open' accepting a first argument of type
>   'ERPSystem.DatabaseConnector' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

My DBConnector Class is :

```
 class DatabaseConnector
{
    private DatabaseConnector databaseConnector;
    private string connectionString = "Data Source=lernlap;Initial Catalog=ERPSystemDB;User ID=sa;Password=sa123";

    public DatabaseConnector()
    {

    }

    private SqlConnection connection;

    private bool Connect()
    {
        try
        {
            connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception) {

            return false;

        }
    }

    internal DatabaseConnector CreateInstance()
    {
        if (databaseConnector == null)
        {
            databaseConnector = new DatabaseConnector();
            databaseConnector.Connect();
        }
        return databaseConnector;
    }
```

Comment: yes but theres no any case sensitivity problem know

Comment: SqlDbType - you had lower case s

Comment: RE: `DatabaseConnector` -- you may want to read this:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/9707060/4068

Comment: @AustinSalonen - I cannot agree with those statements more.  Please do yourself a favor Learner and connect to your database without using DatabaseConnector because clearly is a buggy class.

Comment: Oh, and the whole `new DatabaseConnector().CreateInstance()` construct makes me itch.

Comment: CreateInstence()  that i got in Singleton pattern tuitorial

Comment: @Learner - You don't need to use this class.  Everything your class does is supported by default and `done the correct way` in the default ADO.NET classes.  You are just creating problems, bugs, and using HORRIBLE CODE for no reason.

Comment: @Ramhound Indeed, and Learner, this code is not a singleton pattern. Simply adding a function named CreateInstance doesn't make something a singleton.

Comment: ... I also had a lower case `'s'` .. thank you @javajavajava

Answer (score 12, accepted):

C# is case sensetive...  Try using intellisense.

```
SqlDbType
```

The other errors may disappear if you correct the first one.

---

On a side note, you're going to run into connection/memory leaks without proper resource handling. Personally, I use the `using` statement to avoid the pitfalls.

I'm not entirely certain what "DatabaseConnector" is, possible your own class, but you should probably be using [SqlConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx) instead, or possibly [SqlDatabase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.data.sql.sqldatabase%28v=pandp.31%29.aspx).

Update:  I'm not sure if the DBConnector class is supposed to be a singleton or a factory, or both - so I just simplified my answer to avoid using it.  Ask another question with detail on how to create the pattern you're looking for and provide the DBConnector class.  I think it's do-able, but I just don't have enough info to fix what you have.

```
public static CONN_STR = "Data Source=lernlap;Initial Catalog=ERPSystemDB;User ID=sa;Password=sa123";

  protected void btn_edit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CONN_STR))
        {
          con.Open(); 

          using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tbl_BinCardManager SET ItemName = @ItemName WHERE ItemNo = @ItemNo"), con)
          {

            // TODO: fill in param values with real values
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemName", "my item name");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemNo", 1);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
          }
        }
     }
```

Comment: another thing is in that code near con.Open() & con.close() is red underlined.When i put the cursor on that then i saw Methos Stub Create.(then i saw thatone created in db connector class) Why is that ?

Comment: What exactly IS DatabaseConnector?  Your own class?

Comment: @ChrisGessler - If I were to hazard a guess it was based off this code: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32909/Database-Connector

Comment: @Learner - Those lines are underlined in red because your code won't compile because those methods to do not exists for the `SqlCommand` class.  You havea great deal more research before we can actually help you with additional questions.

Comment: @Learner - the red underline means the method doesn't exist.  When you click "Implement" it puts a method stub in the class for you.  I'm guessing you're not using the DatabaseConnector class properly but I don't have the source to guide you on that.

Comment: @ChrisGessler - You have an error in your code.  The variable `cmd` does not exist yet you attempt to call the `ExecuteNonQuery` method.  This is the reason you should suggest better variable names.

Comment: @Ramhound - sorry... not my code, but i'll fix it.  thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @ChrisGessler - I updated my DBconnector class in my original post

Comment: Well... I see that your DBConnector class is missing a few things.  I'll try to update my answer with something usable, but it might not be easy.

Comment: @ChrisGessler i'm a beginner.no understanding about factory patterns.

Comment: @ChrisGessler - I saw another thing in one tuitorial ..they told PUT connection string in web.config... i tried that also.. LIKE THIS <connectionStrings>
   
    <add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=lernlap;Initial Catalog=ERPSystemDB;User ID=sa;Password=sa123"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
   But i dont know how to use that in my c# file ?

Comment: @Learner - this is outside the scope of your question, but I recommend using Microsoft Enterprise Library which has a UI to add connection strings to your web.config and all the objects needed to connect and retrieve data from your SQL Server instance.

Comment: @ChrisGessler i'm sorry to asking that,but when i tried it out this SQLConnection way,but unfortunately that there was a error know.. then i tried it out in every possible way(then i found this web.config method)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12918/discussion-between-chris-gessler-and-learner)

Answer (score 7):

SqlDbType the s needs to be capitalized!

Answer (score 3):

```
yes but theres no any case sensitivity problem know
```

You actually DO have syntax errors because you used `s` instead of `S`.  Furthermore 
SqlCommand does not have a method called `Open()` nor does it have one for `Close()`

You should be using SqlConnection since it contains the methods `Open()` and `Close()` and set the SqlCommand's `Connection` property to your instance of `SqlConnection` in order to open and close the connection to your database.

Answer (score 2):

You have more errors.

- Based on the way you use it, I think you mean `SqlConnection` instead of `DatabaseConnector`
- You create an SqlCommand named `com`, but refer to it as `cmd`
- You will need to assign the SqlConnection to the SqlCommand, or it will not know which connection to open.
- You only provide 1 parameter to the SqlCommand, while the query needs two (`ItemNo` as well as `ItemName`).

Edit, based on your new source:

- The error "DatabaseConnector' does not contain a definition for 'Open'" can be corrected by writing `con.Connect()` instead of `con.Open()`.
- However, the other error, that it doesn't have a "Close()" function, can't be corrected - there is no way to tell it to close a connection.

Is this your own code?

Comment: Then add a function to it that can close the connection. Or just throw the whole DatabaseConnector away and use the SqlConnection directly.

Comment: when i throughout DatabaseConnector my connectionstring also loss know ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the class made by [The Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32909/Database-Connector) ?

Well, I think the error is because the connection string. The connection string have to be in the class OdbcDatabaseConnector. Well, I never used this class of Code Project, but can be it.

Comment: I'm using SQL database connector

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing with capital 'S' but still get the same error especially in visual studio 2015, then instead of writing 'SqlDbType' , write :
System.Data.SqlDbType

for example:

```
  param[0] = new SqlParameter("@Name", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,50);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its capital 'S' in SqlDbType, after making the correction, right click on the word, mouse on over to resolve option and add the System.Data namespace. worked for me!