# Exception connecting to SQL Server from c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, exception, ado.net

i am working on a simple database project in c sharp and ms sql sever 2008 but im having an error upon compiling the program its poping up this message:

> The type initializer for 'StudentsInformationSystem.DB_conection' threw an exception

My code:

```
namespace StudentsInformationSystem
{
    class DB_Access
    {
        private SqlConnection conn;

        public DB_Access()
        {
            conn = DB_conection.GetConnection(); //this is where i am getting the error on this line of code

        }

       public void add_student(string regNo,string fname, string lname, string phoneNo)
       {
            if (conn.State.ToString() == "closed")
            {
                conn.Open();
            }

            SqlCommand newCmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            newCmd.Connection = conn;
            newCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            newCmd.CommandText = "insert into student values('" + regNo + "','" + fname + "','" + lname + "','" + phoneNo + "')";
            newCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not a compiler error.  Read the InnerException.

Comment: im a newbie mind explaining to me what you mean??like InnerException.

Comment: What error do you get? tell the error sentence please. Most likely it would be something like "connection is not open" is it so?

Comment: what is db_connection called? i think you need to initialize DB_Connection instance.

Comment: @MildredShimz: *Exceptions* occur at execution time. If you're running the code, it must have *compiled* without error. Compile-time errors are the ones which show up in the Visual Studio "Errors" view, such as if you make a typo and try to use a variable which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Injection issues aside, your problem likely comes from comparing ConnectionState to a string.

```
/* this will never be true because "closed" is not equal to "Closed" */
if (conn.State.ToString() == "closed")
{
   conn.Open();
}
```

... should be:

```
if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
    conn.Open();
}
```

You should also get the connection as close to its usage as possible and *never* store it as a class-level variable.

```
using (var conn = DB_conection.GetConnection())
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    // use conn & cmd

    // they will be closed & disposed of when they leave this block
}
```

Comment: its still giving me the same problem,i have edited it to show you where exactly im getting the error

Comment: @MildredShimz:  My answer is still valid for other issues you'll encounter.  To adequately answer your question, you'll need to post the code for `DB_connection`.

Comment: As for actually having the `DB_connection` class at all, please see this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/9707060/4068

Comment: im am reposting the question again

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that there is no problem with your `DB_conection` (you have not shared it's details)

Few improvements in the code

```
public void add_student(string regNo,string fname, string lname, string phoneNo)
{
     if (conn.State == ConnectionSate.Closed)          
            conn.Open();         
     SqlCommand newCmd = conn.CreateCommand();
     newCmd.CommandText = "insert into student values('" + regNo + "','" + fname + "','" + lname + "','" + phoneNo + "')";
     newCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I will recommend to not close the connection after each query for the sake of quick accessibility of database, and you are already doing this. However after using a data-reader you should close the data-reader, otherwise it could cause some error

//newCmd.Connection = conn; No need you have done this in above statement

//newCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; No need, it is by default

Answer (score 0):

`Type initializer for [class name] threw an exception.`

This indicates an exception raised within the static constructor of a class.  You need to check the static constructor of class `DB_conection`.  Its code will be executed before the static method call `GetConnection` in the code you've shown.

If you run your code in a debugger I'm sure the source of the exception will be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you have fixed the problem since now , but if
the application you a writing is from a youtube user tutorial ,

the problem is on the app.confing xml you write at first http://www.youtube.com/watch?list=UL53a-mKN01jQ&v=53a-mKN01jQ&feature=player_detailpage#t=479s

remove the `<configSections></configSections>and leave <connectionStrings><add ..</connection Strings>` and it should work