# IDbConnection factory using Dapper

Tags: c#, asp.net, dapper

I using dapper in my ASP.NET WebForms solution.

All my classes which handles data retrieves an open connection from this base class

```
public abstract class SalesDb : IDisposable
{
    protected static IDbConnection OpenConnection()
    {
        IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SalesDb"].ConnectionString);
        connection.Open();
        return connection;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        OpenConnection().Dispose();
    }
}
```

Example of a service class that uses this base class

```
public class LeadService : SalesDb
{
    public IEnumerable<LeadDto> Select()
    {
        using (IDbConnection connection = OpenConnection())
        {
            return connection.Query<LeadDto>("Lead_Select",
                null, null, true, null, CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any disadvantage that `OpenConnection(`) method in the base class is static and return a new instance for every call?

Comment: If you are going to do a lot of calls to the database you will have this overhead of creating and destroying connections to the database all the time.

Comment: Are you using connection-pooling(default)?

Comment: But i already do that in my service method "Select".

Comment: You are creating a new connection in dispose? That won't work! Use a simple loop with more than 100 iterations and you'll probably see some kind of exceptions(too many open connections etc.). In any case i expect serious performance problems since the pool needs to create new physical connections consecutively.

Comment: If connection-pooling is ON by default i am using it.

Comment: @anpe: Yes, you're using the default [SQL Server Connection Pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx). I would not [**reinvent the connection-pool**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705637/executereader-requires-an-open-and-available-connection-the-connections-curren/9707060#9707060). My advice is: don't use that class, all the more in asp.net.

Comment: Thnak you @TimSchmelter. I will adapt my methods, according to the link "dont reinvent the connection-pool". Can you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are creating a new connection in dispose? That won't work! Use a simple loop with more than 100 iterations( max pool size default is 100 ) and you'll probably see some kind of exceptions(*too many open connections*, [*ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705637/executereader-requires-an-open-and-available-connection-the-connections-curren) etc.).

In any case i expect serious performance problems since the pool needs to create new physical connections consecutively.

I would not reinvent the [**Connection-Pool**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx). My advice is: don't use that class, all the more in asp.net.

[Don't poach on the Connection-Pool's territory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9707060/284240) ;-)

**But** note that both of your questions can be answered with *No*. The static method is not a problem(unlike a static connection) and also not that it always returns a new connection(since the pool would return connections that are currently not in use). But the main problem of your class is the `dispose` which creates connections and opens them.