# c# get or set accessor expected

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm attempting to create a method that I can call on any form in order to establish a mysql connection. This is the code I have

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace micromini
{
    public class dbcon
    {
        public void dbconnector
        {
            string strConnection = "host=50.87.144.250; database=twhalen_storage; username=twhalen_software; password=Karatom14!;";
            MySqlConnection conSQL = new MySqlConnection(strConnection);
            try
            {
                conSQL.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string exstring = ex.ToString();
                MessageBox.Show(exstring);
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome!");
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get is A `get or set accessor expected`. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish with that method but don't do it.  [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9707060/4068) for a reason why (the answer is about SQL Server but the concept applies to database connections in general).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the () after the method name

```
 public void dbconnector()
```

This is required to differentiate a method from a property that requires the [get/set syntax](http://www.dotnetperls.com/property)

However, this code opens the connection in a local variable and doesn't return it so it is basically useless.  Not to mention that you don't close and dispose the connection.

In this way you rely on the [Garbage Collector](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/understanding-garbage-collection-in-.net/) to dispose the variable and free the connection.
Used too many times in a row, this code could lead to the `Too many open connections` error

Answer (score 9):

You missed the parentheses `()` for the parameters after the name of the method, which is an obligatory part of the signature, so the compiler try to analyze your method as a property.

Answer (score 3):

Without the paranthesis (), you have declared a Property not a method and a Property requires get and set accesors. Put () at the name of your method.

```
public void dbconnector()
```