# Error: ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is open

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have mvc 4 website with DataHelperClass below to execute query. My problem is sometimes, website through exeception as title. I used using block to dispose SqlCommand and SqlDataAdapter but not success.

Please help me, sorry for my english.

```
        try
        {
            if (_conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                _conn.Open();

            using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, _conn))
            {
                sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                if (parameters != null)
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);

                //// check transaction is exist
                if (_trans != null)
                    sqlCommand.Transaction = _trans;

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand))
                {
                    sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
                }

                return dt;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            //// close connection automatically if transaction is not exist
            if (_trans == null) { _conn.Close(); }
        }
```

Comment: Most likely  `static SqlConnection _conn` that you did not show in the sample is the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It may be caused that your connection is not really opened, because when this code is called:

```
if (_conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
      _conn.Open();
```

Connection state could be: `Broken`, or `Connecting` or `Fetching` (See all [enum list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.connectionstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

This may happen if you try to share your connection between many threads. I think you need to create a new connection each time this method is called. You can find many examples how to do it, including [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

**EDIT**:

There is a great answer for such a question: [ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is Connecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705637/executereader-requires-an-open-and-available-connection-the-connections-curren)

But if you really-really need it, try to prevent using the same connection with two or more threads by using `lock` (it is wrong actually, see the link above):

```
lock(_conn)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand))
    {
        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had replaced if (_conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) _conn.Open(); with if (_trans == null) {_conn = new SqlConnection(Utility.Connect); _conn.Open(); } but problem cannot solve