# Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed. getting this error?

Tags: c#, ado.net

Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed. getting this error asp.net with c#?
i have used this code

```
string catalogNo = string.Empty;
string deleteID = string.Empty;  
Globals.Initialize("Text", "select CatelogNo,DeleteID from tbl_admin_quotation where QuotationID='" + quotation3 + "' order by id asc");
Globals.dr = Globals.cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (Globals.dr.Read() == true)
{
    catalogNo = Globals.dr[0].ToString();
    deleteID = Globals.dr[1].ToString();
    decimal taqty = 0;
    Globals.Initialize("Text", "select qty from tbl_admin_quotation where DeleteID='" + deleteID + "'");
    Globals.dr3 = Globals.cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (Globals.dr3.Read() == true)
    {
        taqty = Convert.ToDecimal(Globals.dr3[0].ToString());
    }
    Globals.dr3.Dispose();
    Globals.dr3.Close();
    Globals.Initialize("Text", "select Pqty,Hqty from  tbl_admin_stock where CatelogNo='" + catalogNo + "'");
    Globals.dr = Globals.cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (Globals.dr.Read() == true)
    {
        if (Convert.ToDecimal(Globals.dr[0].ToString()) != 0)
        {
            Globals.Initialize("Text", "update tbl_admin_stock set Pqty=Pqty+'" + Convert.ToDecimal(taqty) + "' where CatelogNo='" + catalogNo + "'");
            Globals.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        else if (Convert.ToDecimal(Globals.dr[1].ToString()) != 0)
        {
            Globals.Initialize("Text", "update tbl_admin_stock set Hqty=Hqty-'" + Convert.ToDecimal(taqty) + "' where CatelogNo='" + catalogNo + "'");
            Globals.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    Globals.dr.Dispose();
    Globals.dr.Close();
}

  Globals.dr.Dispose();
Globals.dr.Close(); 
 Globals.Initialize("Text", "delete from tbl_admin_quotation where  QuotationId=@QuotationId");
Globals.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QuotationId", quotation3);
Globals.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

UpdatePanelMain.Update();
GridviewBind();
```

Comment: To be honest, i would throw your `Globals` class into the garbage can since it's just a source of nasty errors. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705637/executereader-requires-an-open-and-available-connection-the-connections-curren

Comment: Yeah. Wholy crap - you use a global holder for non global objects?  Seen a lot of bad code, this one hits first place. And no use of using. What about you get your code cleaned up and start following best practices - then errors based on not so nice code will disappear.

Comment: You should have this code reviewed and the design reconsidered. Rewrite FTW.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter -Thank u lot

Answer (score 0):

If you've code with obvious problems and problems you can't find, fix the obvious problems first and then the obscure problems will likely become obvious:

Get rid of the globals rubbish and put `using` in the appropriate places and then having the `Dispose()` called from that rather than explicitly will also fix this problem.

Comment: -can u show anyone example of using condition?Thank in Advance