# Random behavior: "The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open."

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, exception

This is very strange, it only happens sometimes although this piece of code is executed often.

I have this code running like every 5 seconds and it works fine, but sometimes i get the exception saved on my log.

**Exception msg:** The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.

```
 public class Log
{

    static SqlConnection sqlConnection{get; set;}

    public Log()
    {
        sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(CNN_STRING);
    }



    public static void Save(){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.Append("UPDATE Blabla SET ...");

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), sqlConnection);


         try
        {
            if (sqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open) { sqlConnection.Close(); }
            sqlConnection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlConnection.Close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.AddLog("Log ", 1, string.Concat("Query: ", sb.ToString(), 
                       "Exception    message: ", e.Message));
        }
        finally
        {
            if (sqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open) { sqlConnection.Close(); }
        }
   }
```

any clues?

Comment: Consider to use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`.

Comment: If the connection is already open, why close it and re-open it again? It isn't the fastest and there are costs. Odds are the connection is still closing when you are trying to open the connect again.

Comment: Show the declaration of `sqlConnection`, is it `static`? Then make it a local variable and you're done.

Comment: @TimSchmelter it is static, because the method is also static

Comment: i mean, it is a static class, that have some static functions which use the connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A static connection is not a good idea with ASP.NET since every request would share this connection which will cause locks at it's best or even errors like yours.

Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9707060/284240) i've posted some time ago is helpful. So don't make it static and use the `using`-statement.

```
using(var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(CNN_STRING))
using (var command = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), sqlConnection))
{
    sqlConnection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

You don't need to close the connection since that is done by the using-statement(dispose).

Comment: thanks for the link, now i have to change 600 lines of code because i encapsulate ADO.NET functionality into a DB helper Classes!

Comment: by the way, "using" will always close/dispose the connection right?