# No rows with parameterized SqlCommand

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I created a function which checks if an username already exists in DB.
I am using `SqlCommand` with sql-parameterd to avoid Sql-Injection. To execute I should use the class `SqlAccess`, because the whole existing project is built with that.

The Code I've written...

```
'Check if username already exists'
Public Shared Function usernameExists(Username As String) As Boolean
    Dim sqlCommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("Select UserLogin From [User] where UserLogin = '@Username'")
    Dim param As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("Username", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    param.Value = Username
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(param)

Try
    SQLAccess.OpenSQLConnection(sqlCommand, SetDBConnectionData) 'SqlDBConnectionData is a function which returns a structSQlAccess'
    Dim dsUsers As DataSet = SQLAccess.SQLQueryToDS(sqlCommand)

    If dsUsers.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    Return True 'TODO - Error Mgs
End Try

End Function
```

But it doesn't work, the `DataSet` does not contain rows. Could anyone please show me how to do it properly?

Comment: What is the exception message?

Comment: There's no exception. The result is null. I don't get any users even if I wrote an existing username. That's the problem.

Comment: So take a look at Tim Schmelter answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put the parameter in apostrophes as here:

```
"Select UserLogin From [User] where UserLogin = '@Username'"
```

but as here:

```
"Select UserLogin From [User] where UserLogin = @Username"
```

Also, i assume that `SQLAccess` is a custom class which manages the connection. I would strongly advise against such a helper class in ASP.NET since it's just a source of nasty errors, all the more if your connection is `Shared`:

[ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is Connecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705637/executereader-requires-an-open-and-available-connection-the-connections-curren/9707060#9707060)

Comment: Thank you. Your solution works. 
You're right. It's a very old project. We should consider rebuilding it. Thank you very much for your input and suggestion. It was very helpful.