# Get the element from itemTemplate in gridview asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, itemtemplate

I want to ask a question, I'm actually looking for a way to modify the status of a textbox in my gridview, I'm quite lost since I just started this language a few weeks ago and i can't find a satisfying answer (maybe I apply them the wrong way maybe you will be able to help me there. Here is my code :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="centrer">
            <asp:Image ID="IMG_attente" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/1px.gif" Height="32px" />
        </div>
        <asp:Panel ID="panListes" runat="server" Visible="false" CssClass="formulaire">
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="LabelErreur" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
            <asp:GridView ID="ListePieceFlash" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceListePieceFlash"
                OnRowEditing="ListePieceFlash_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="ListePieceFlash_RowCancelingEdit"
                EnableModelValidation="True" SkinID="Source_DarkBlue" AllowPaging="True" DataKeyNames="NumOF"
                OnRowCommand="ListePieceFlash_RowCommand" Width="100%" AllowSorting="True">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/annuler.gif" CommandName="cancel"
                                CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" ToolTip="Annuler" />
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/okvert.gif" CommandName="save"
                                CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" ToolTip="Sauvegarder" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnEdit" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/edit.png" CommandName="edit"
                                CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" ToolTip="Sélectionner" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="NumSerieLabel" runat="server" Text="NumSerie"></asp:Label></HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="NumSerie" runat="server" OnTextChanged="OnNumSerieChanged" /></ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="SymboleLabel" runat="server" Text="Symbole"></asp:Label></HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Symbole" runat="server" Enabled="False" OnTextChanged="OnSymboleChanged" /></ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>                        
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceListePieceFlash" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PRMConnectionString %>"
                SelectCommand="exec [dbo].[getListePieceFlash]"></asp:SqlDataSource>                
        </asp:Panel>            
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

As you can see my "Symbole" TextBox is disabled at start but I want it to be enabled when i fill the first one and there is more than one element, here is the code behind (the SQL part is a stored procedure):

```
protected void OnNumSerieChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        numSerieValue = (sender as TextBox).Text;
        var con = Sql.Instance.ObtenirConnexionSql();
        SqlCommand cmd = ObtenirCommande(con);
        cmd.CommandText = "dbo.getListPiece";
        Int32 count = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        if (count > 1)
            (ListePieceFlash.FindControl("Symbole") as TextBox).Enabled = true;
}
```

The problem is on the last line and I don't really know how to get over it actually, can someone help me? Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

`ListePieceFlash.FindControl("Symbole")` returns `null` because you cannot find the `TextBox` via  `GridView.FindControl`. The `NamingContainer` of the `TextBox` is the `GridViewRow`.

You get it  by casting the `Sender` in `OnNumSerieChanged` to `TextBox` and it's `NamingContainer` property to `GridViewRow`. Then use `row.FindControl("Symbole")` to find the target `TextBox`:

```
protected void OnNumSerieChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox NumSerie = (TextBox) sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow) NumSerie.NamingContainer;
    TextBox Symbole = (TextBox) row.FindControl("Symbole");
    // ...
}
```

Note that i strongly advise against such helper classes in ASP.NET which hold and return database objects like your `Sql.Instance.ObtenirConnexionSql()`. [It can be a source of nasty errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705637/executereader-requires-an-open-and-available-connection-the-connections-curren).