# how to populate checkedlist box in vb using search item text box

Tags: vb.net

i made program to populate employe name in checkedlist box. now i need a search box for searching items from the combo box.when i typing the matching items must list out in the checked list box.for that how i code in vb.net ?.
in key press even driven section i give the code but its not working properly.Please provide sufficient information. my code is given below

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

```
    Dim conobj As Class1
    conobj = New Class1
    conobj.connection()

    Dim str1 = "select distinct e.vc_empname xxxxxxx e.vc_empname like '" & Me.TextBox1.Text & "%' order by e.vc_empname"

    conobj.readdata1(str1)
    CheckedListBox1.DataSource = conobj.ds.Tables(0)
    CheckedListBox1.DisplayMember = "vc_empname"
    CheckedListBox1.ValueMember = "vc_empname"

End Sub
```

Comment: _" but its not working properly"_ and _you_ are asking for " sufficient information"?!

Comment: sory guys,,then please give correct code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if "but its not working properly" is very vague i'll give it a try. Use the `As`clause to specify the alias. Also, use `Where` to filter records:

```
Dim str1 = "select distinct e.vc_empname As xxxxxxx e.vc_empname Where vc_empname  like '%" & Me.TextBox1.Text & "%' order by e.vc_empname"
```

Note that you should always use sql-parameters to prevent sql-injection and other issues. I also strongly [discourage  from global connection classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705637/executereader-requires-an-open-and-available-connection-the-connections-curren/9707060#9707060) like your `Class1` which also holds the connection. All the more if it is `Shared`/`static`.   This can cause issues with connection-pooling which is enabled by default. It's also more difficult to use the `Using`-statement (which you should use) if you don't expose the connection and other ADO.NET objects. It's also difficult to pass the sql-parameters if the method `readdata1` doesn't accepts them.

Comment: thanks for the reply.its not an alias..ites a very lengthy code..so i just put the xxxx,,

Comment: @achu: then _"use Where to filter records"_ and the rest of the answer remain.

Comment: @achu: how to _give like_, what does that mean? I have shown how to use `LIKE` in sql.