# Checking for record existence in column sql

Tags: sql, asp.net

I am trying to check if the user select (`u.userId`) is not in the column (`urid`) then only return true and run the other function. If the user selected data already exists, then return false. I get it with return void.. what happens? I'm still new in asp.net, hoping for some help. Thanks.

```
 public string URID { get; set; }

 public void urid_existence(User u)
 {
     DBHandler dbh = new DBHandler();
     dbh.OpenConnection();

     string sql = "select urid from FCS_COUGRP";

     if (u.UserID != u.URID)
     {
         userH.changeUrserGroup(u);
         return true;
     }
     else
     {
         return false;
     }
}
```

Comment: 1) Does it compile? Change return type to bool. 2) Dispose your connection. 3) What's the point to have SQL command you don't execute? 4) Create a SqlCommand and execute a query. You may do everything in SQL using COUNT(*) and WHERE with ExecuteScalar()

Comment: Note that the class `DBHandler` [seems fishy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705637/executereader-requires-an-open-and-available-connection-the-connections-curren) to me, what does it do? Your sql query also is pointless because you don't use it and because you should use a `Where`-clause to filter in the database, f.e. if you want to check if a record with a given ID exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`void`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yah0tteb.aspx) means that the method does not return anything, but you want to return a `bool`. So this is the correct signature:

```
public bool urid_existence(User u)
{
   // ...
   if (u.UserID != u.URID)
   {
      userH.changeUrserGroup(u);
      return true;
   }
   else
   {
       return false;
   }
}
```