# Cannot implicity convert type error

Tags: c#, executereader

Trying to fill Combobox with data from a database and I'm using ExecuteReader as below, but when I try to instantiate my connection it shows me the error

> Cannot implicitly convert type error

My DBConnect class code:

```
public class DBConnect
{
        private SqlConnection connection;
        private string servername = "10.1.76.109,1433";
        private string database = "EngLib";
        private string dbuser;
        private string userpassword;


        public DBConnect()
        {

        }

        public void doDBConnect(string dbuserform, string userpasswordform)
        {
            dbuser = dbuserform;
            userpassword = userpasswordform;
        }


        public void Initialize()
        {

        }

        public bool openConnection()
        {
            string connectionString;
            connectionString = "Server=" + servername + ";Database=" + database + ";user id=" + dbuser + ";Password=" + userpassword;
            Console.WriteLine(connectionString);
            connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                return true;
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                switch (ex.Number)
                {
                    case 0:
                        MessageBox.Show("Não é possível contactar o servidor. Entre em contato com o administrador");
                        break;

                    case 18456:
                        MessageBox.Show("Usuário/Senha inválidos, tente novamente");
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }

}
```

My form code:

```
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataReader rdr = null;
        DBConnect sqlConnection;
        sqlConnection = new DBConnect();
        sqlConnection.doDBConnect(dbuserform: "usertest", userpasswordform: "usertest");
         {
            try
            {

                {
                    sqlConnection.openConnection();
                    SqlCommand sqlCmd;
                    sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Material FROM EngLib");
                    sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConnection;
                    SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

                    while (sqlReader.Read())
                    {
                        comboBox1.Items.Add(sqlReader["Material"].ToString());
                    }

                    sqlReader.Close();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                // close the reader
                if (rdr != null)
                {
                    rdr.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The user and password in the code is just temporary.

Comment: Could you please remove the irrelevant code? Please indicate the the line that shows the error and include the related snippets only. Thank you

Comment: Out of theme - you should ALWAYS close/dispose your connections to DB

Comment: Do you really need this class that just causes issues which you otherwise wouldn't have if you'd create the connection where you use it, best by using the `using`-statement?! Other things speak against using a DB-class. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9707060/284240

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
DBConnect sqlConnection;
SqlCommand sqlCmd;
sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConnection;
```

`SqlCommand` expects that `Connection` is of type `SqlConnection`, but you are assigning your own class `DBConnect`.

Possible fixes:

Expose the `connection` property on `DBConnect` and use it.

Inherit `DBConnect` from `SqlConnection`.

Use `SqlConnection` directly.

An additional note: you are not disposing the `SqlConnection` inside your `DBConnect` class, which can lead to `StackOverflowException`. You should implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was the problem and now it's solved.

Comment: Glad to help! Please accept the answer if this was the problem.