# I have error when I am trying to connect my database

Tags: c#, database, connection, runtime-error

Below is my code. Where I am passing connection string in Openconnection() function. But when Openconnection method is invoked, I am getting error.

```
 public class dbconn
    {
        string ConnetionString = null;
        string State = "";
        SqlConnection cnn;
    public string openconnection()
    {
        ConnetionString = @"Data Source=myservername;Initial Catalog=mydbname;Integrated Security=True";
        cnn = new SqlConnection(ConnetionString);
        try
        {
            cnn.Open();
            return State;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             ...............
        }
    }

    public string closeconnection()
    {
        ConnetionString = @"Data Source=myservername;Initial Catalog=mydbname;Integrated Security=True";
        cnn = new SqlConnection(ConnetionString);
        try
        {
            cnn.Close();
            return State;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           .........
        }
    }



}
```

when I am trying to call this class from my c# code part like

```
public dbconn dbcon;
private void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string State="";
  try
  {
    State= dbcon.openconnection();//*** Error in this line
    if (State!= "")
    {
      MessageBox.Show(State, "Lost Connection");
    }
 }
}
```

In *** part I've got error.

Comment: You should show the detail of the error

Comment: You're missing the `catch(){}` after your `try`. and what is the actual error?

Comment: Why don't you tell us _what_ error you get? I guess it's an exception, and the exception message probably tells you what went wrong.

Comment: please read up on how to do a `try{}catch{}` properly and show us the error message

Comment: `dbcon = new  dbconn();`? Maybe?

Comment: I [advise against using such helper classes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9707060/284240) that hold the sql-connection and manage opening/closing it, instead use the `using`-statement wherever you need to access the database.

Comment: I have catch and finally parts and my error is


NullReferenceException was Unhandled
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in VeriTabanı.exe

Comment: @FakeCaleb I tried it error has gone but still can't open connection it went to catch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment, I was right. You need to instantiate your dbconn object.

```
dbcon = new dbconn();
```

Overall though, I'd advise against using this sort of practice for SQL connections. Please look into `using` for whenever you're doing any sort of database access. (As Tim Schmelter has already stated in the comments)

Comment: I didn't get this error this time but my connection didn't opened

Comment: I can't help from 'didn't opened'. What error are you getting? What exactly is happening?

Comment: I don't get any error my program trying to open and it's going to catch then

Comment: I recommend printing the exception. `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.message);` in your catch and read whats happening, that will massively help you

Comment: I have ProcDurum = urunekle.proc(int.Parse(cbmüşteriseç.ToString()),txtürünadı.‌​ToString(),dtcürüngi‌​riştarihi.ToString()‌​,float.Parse(txtkilo‌​.ToString()), int.Parse(txtürünadeti.ToString()),txtkasatipi.ToString(),tx‌​türünözelliği.ToStri‌​ng(),txtplaka.ToStri‌​ng());


in my code line and I have got catch expection in there

Comment: public urunekleproc urunekle=new urunekleproc(); i have that code line also

Comment: I think I understand what is wrong I have stored procedure and when I am trying to add record with using storeprocedureclass I have got error. @FakeCaleb

Comment: It seems that way (though due to the formatting and language, I'm struggling to comprehend the exact issue), as none of what you showed us above relates to what you are showing me here. I'm glad you figured out you're issue though.

Comment: Thanks again for your help :)