# How can i do multiple async calls to my webapi at the same time without getting errors?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

I have the problem when i do 1 fetch it works but when i try to fetch 4 calls att the same time 1 succedes and the other 3 fails.

```
    public IHttpActionResult GetAll() {
        var products = _context.Products
            .ToList();

        if (products == null)
            return NotFound();

        return Ok(products.Select(x => CreateDto(x)));
    }
```

This is the error

```
An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"There is already 
an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be 
closed first.
```

When i google this they suggest i add to the connectionsstring

```
MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

Then i get another error

```
ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. 
The connection's current state is open.
```

The suggested by google is then. That i use the dbcontext wrong [ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is Connecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705637/executereader-requires-an-open-and-available-connection-the-connections-curren)

My dbcontext looks like. So im not doing any funky with that.

```
public class PContext : DbContext {

    public IDbSet<Products> Products{ get; set; }

}
```

When im return Ok(products.Select(x => CreateDto(x))); in the first line of code i do a lot of selects and things like that. If i remove some heavy code here it works. But it feels like the problem is that this stuff cant handle multiple calls. I mean it should depend on the size of the job it should return when its finished.

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably you have a single dbcontext used in multiple requests. Make sure you create one per request.

Comment: I have a basecontroller that runs

        protected readonly PContext _context;

        public ApiControllerBase(PContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

Comment: And when is that context created, the one that is passed to the base controller?

Comment: Im not sure from the controller i call 

        public ProductsController(PdbContext context)
            : base(context) {
        }

This is confusing. Its not invoking new

Comment: I tried calling new to the base the result is the same. Its not working

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head try this

```
public IHttpActionResult GetAll() {
    var products = _context.Products;

    if (products == null)
        return NotFound();
    var convertToListFirst = products.Select(x => CreateDto(x)).ToList();
    return Ok(convertToListFirst);
}
```

I remember converting toList at the wrong time in the past.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have already tried this. Then i get the same  error: ExceptionMessage=ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is open. When having the MultipleActiveResultSets=True set. And without the first error: ExceptionMessage=There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.