# ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is open

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection

I am getting an error:

> ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection.
>   The connection's current state is open.

I have used the `con.Open();`, but I'm getting the same error.
Please help me on this.

```
static string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MessageDB"].ToString();
static SqlConnection _sqlconn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

public static void Message(MessageLog messageLog)
{
    try
    {
        _sqlconn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        _sqlconn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = _sqlconn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT_MESSAGE";

        SqlParameter APPID = cmd.CreateParameter();
        APPID.ParameterName = @"@MessageID";
        APPID.DbType = DbType.Int16;
        APPID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        APPID.Value = messageLog.MessageID;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(MessageID);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        _sqlconn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (_sqlconn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            _sqlconn.Close();
        }

        ExceptionLogger.LogException(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: kindly format your question properly

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201754/executenonquery-requires-an-open-and-available-connection-the-connections-curr

Comment: IMHO, wrap the `Command` and `SqlConnection` in `Using` statements; then your object will get disposed when done with them...

Answer (score 0):

IMHO Your problem is using static connection variable. 
`static SqlConnection _sqlconn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);` and then you assigned it again which is doesn't make any sense. I would change your code a bit:

```
static string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MessageDB"].ToString();
public static void Message(MessageLog messageLog)
{
   using(var _sqlconn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
   {
      using(var cmd = new SqlCommand())
      {
          cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
          cmd.CommandText = "INSERT_MESSAGE";
          cmd.Connection = _sqlconn;

          cmd.Parameters.Add("@MessageID", DbType.Int16).Value = messageLog.MessageID;
          try
          {
              if(_sqlconn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) _sqlconn.Open()

              cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
               ExceptionLogger.LogException(ex);
          } 
          finally
          { 
               if (_sqlconn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
               {
                  _sqlconn.Close();
               }
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Benefit of that syntax?

- All disposable will be disposed.
- Connection will be always closed regardless of exceptions or normal execution flows.
- No attempts to open already open connections.
- Connection always available because it's taken from connection pool every time and not "freeze" for static variable.